# How can i modify joomla to be an OpenID provider?

Tags: joomla, openid, openid-provider

i'm trying to find joomla plugins or another components to make joomla an OpenID providerID itself with his database.

Any idea of how can i accomplish this idea?

Comment: J1.5 had an OpenId plugin with installation, perhaps that could be adapted to J2.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only extension I'm aware of that does this is the [relatively new JFusion Connect](http://www.jfusion.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=7355) from the people that make the very reputable [JFusion](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-bridges/3723).